# vim how to highlight current buffer in :ls

Tags: vim

I recently discovered the use of buffers in vim and I was wondering if it is possible to highlight the line of the current buffer in the window which show `:ls` result?

I know that the current buffer is marked with `%` but highlighting the line would be easier to see.

Any vim-master can give me hand with this?

Comment: I think you need modify the vim source codes.

Comment: Uh that sounds a little bit too hard for me :/ Couldn't it be done with a plugin or a simplier trick?

Comment: If you're only interested in an overview of your buffers and you're not one of those guys who have 100 buffers opened simultaneously you might want to have a look at [airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline#smarter-tab-line)

Comment: @swenzel: Thanks, that seems pretty good for what I want. I had already heard about airline but didn't know it showed buffers like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in option, so you'd either have to directly modify Vim's sources, or write a custom command in Vimscript. I would not recommend any of those.

For the latter, you can use `:redir` to capture the output of built-in `:ls`, `split()` into lines, then `:echo` each in a loop, matching with the leading `%` to detect the current one, and in that case use `:echohl` to change the highlighting group. The [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) could allow you to install that new `:LS` command over the built-in `:ls`, but again, I think this is too cumbersome for too little effect.

Comment: Ok thank you for the heading. Indeed that seems like a big job for a small result... I'm a little surprise to see that this feature isn't more easily accessible: I mean vim is able to highlight a line, it is able to match some patterns, I can't be the only one who thought about it and the community is full of people way more talented than me. Do you know what is the reason which prevented the community to do it?

Comment: Yes, such patch would be rather simple; but you'd need another highlight group for that, documentation, tests, etc. Also, many Vim users like simplicity; too many colors are perceived as distracting. (On the other hand, multi-color, symbol-rich statuslines are also quite widespread, so there's also the opposite group there.)

Comment: Of course I understand that it can't satify everybody but as you say some people like color :) That could be an occasion to make my first contribution to this awesome project.